# How to get new modified index of element if we reorder it using drag n drop in Primeng orderlist

Tags: angular, primeng

I am quite new to Angular, I want to get the modified index of elements once we drag n drop the orderlist element and change the sequence. Don't know to use onReorder event of orderlist.

Can anyone help me with this?

image.component.html

```
<div class=image>
<app-header></app-header>
<p-orderList [value]="thumbnail" header="Hotel View" [listStyle]="{'height':'400px'}" filterBy="tag"
 filterPlaceholder="Filter by Tag" dragdrop="true" onReorder="onReorderNodes($event)">
    <ng-template let-thumbnail pTemplate="item">
        <div class="ui-helper-clearfix">
            <img [src]="'data:image/jpg;base64,'+thumbnail.image |secure| async" width="100">
            <div  style="font-size:20px;float:right;margin:15px 5px 0 0">
                <b>Tag</b>-Tag1,tag2,tag....
                <b>Year</b>-2010
            </div>
        </div>
        {{$event}}
    </ng-template>
</p-orderList>
</div>
```

image.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { NgxSpinnerService } from "ngx-spinner"; 
@Component({
  selector: 'app-image',
  templateUrl: './image.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./image.component.css']
})   

export class ImageComponent implements OnInit {


  thumbnail: any;
  
  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private SpinnerService: NgxSpinnerService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    let imgAssetId = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('assetId');
    if (imgAssetId != null) {
      this.getHotelAllImages(imgAssetId);
    }
    else {
      alert("No images present for asset " + imgAssetId)
    }
  }

  getHotelAllImages(assetId: string) {
    this.SpinnerService.show();  
    console.log("Asset ID: " + assetId)
    this.http.get<any>(this.url2 + Number(assetId))
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.thumbnail = data;
        this.SpinnerService.hide(); 
        if (this.thumbnail == null) {
          alert("No images present for Asset Id:" + assetId);
        }
        console.log("output " + this.thumbnail)
      })
  }    
}
```

How should I get a new sequence after performing drag and drop on orderlist?

Comment: Please click the primafaces tag, read its info tab. Are you really using this?

Comment: I have the same problem. Unfortunately, there is no good documentation for this matter on PrmieNg website!!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I used the onReorder event since it notifies when the list is ordered then I use the list that I pass to the p-orderList since it automatically updates it with the order that was set by the user, it means that you just need to follow this ordered list and you don't need any current or previous index because you already have the list ordered.

For example, I have an activity list, it is an object with a name, Id, and order property. I just update the order property with the index + 1 to set my order and then update this activity in my backend, then when this list comes back to the front end I make sure I order this list by this order property.

This is how I do it in the HTML

```
  <p-orderList
         (onReorder)="onOrderActivity()"
         styleClass="activity-order-list"
         [value]="activities"
         [dragdrop]="true">
      <ng-template</ng-template>
  </p-orderList>
```

This is how I did it in ts file, in this case, activities get the right order after drag and drop.

```
 onReorder() {
    activities.forEach((a, index) => (a.Order = index + 1));
    this.saveActivity(activity);
  }
```

Sort method

```
  sortByActivityOrder(a,b):number{
    a.Order - b.Order 
   }
```

I hope it helps somebody since it was posted a few months ago